# How effective would a heartbeat sensor be at stopping spam?

Tags: authentication, android, multi-factor

Making an android app (for fun) that communicates with a server I am trying to come up with out of the box security ideas, one of them would be to use a heartbeat sensor instead of a captcha for avoiding spam. How effective would it be? It is not a password, just a mean to prove me as human. For my app it doesn't need to be very strong (just a competition between siblings) but would this be usable in large scale apps?

Comment: What is the response the sensor would send back to the server that could not be imitated by a bot?

Comment: @TTT The app is supposed to communicate with the server (sending a message) but the heartbeat wouldn't. It would be authenticated by the app itself. (Maybe there is a better way I am not aware of thought)

Comment: Why do you think they are using your app? Opposition is expected to craft requests to your server using some other tool after observing the requests your app makes.

Comment: @notstoreboughtdirt good point, still I have token(like) system in the makings. I am only concerned with requests coming from the app itself.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As the comments say, security needs to be done server-side, not client-side.

If somebody wanted to send spam to your server, they would not use your app to do it, they would sniff the data packets that your app is sending to the server and then build their own app that sends those same packets with their message instead.

For this reason, in security analysis we always treat the client as if it is malicious and make sure the server is not relying on the client to perform the security checks. In the case of a captcha, the results are sent to the server to be verified before it will process your request. You could send the heartbeat data to the server, but I'm not sure what that accomplishes because the spammer could just record a heartbeat and send that over and over. You could also probably make a heartbeat generator pretty easily based on a random number generator.

Inventing new security technology is hard, it takes a lot of people and a lot of failed attempts to get it right. There's an old saying "Anyone can create something that they themselves can not break, but creating something that nobody can break is much harder". I like that you are thinking outside the box and asking questions. Keep exploring :)

Comment: Makes sense, i am not really experienced in the area but I am aiming to start changing that. Will try to make something along those lines then. Just as an information, how good are captchas really? I am referring to the more standard ones.

Comment: That's not really my area of expertise (I'm a low level crypto guy). The wikipedia page on captchas seems to have a discussion on their effectiveness. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/CAPTCHA